# What are limits of Modulus Switching in BFV encryption?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, ring-lwe

I want to understand the limits of modulus switching in BFV.

Lets assume $q$ represents ciphertext modulus and $t$ represents plaintext modulus.
$q$ is set to a $60$ bit value and $t$ is set to $20$ bits value.

Now we are given a BFV ciphertext $c$ based on above parameter choices.
Also assume that due to holomorphic operations, the noise e in $c$ is around $35$ bits.

Now can I switch this ciphertext to modulus $q'$ which is of $30$ bits.

Note switched ciphertext should still be valie as $q'>2t|e'|$, where |e'| is infinity norm of error in switch ciphertext ~ around $5$ bits.

Comment: What is $e'$ here? The noise of the ciphertext after the modulus switching? How do you compute its norm?

Comment: wouldn't infinity norm of $e'$ will be around $5$ bits?

Comment: It depends on $N$, the degree of the cyclotomic ring, but usually this norm is larger than 5 bits.

Comment: can you refer me to some resource that I could read to know how is it calculated

Comment: I added it as an answer. Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short**

Consider you are working on the ring $R_Q = \mathbb{Z}_Q[X] / \langle X^N + 1 \rangle$. As a rule of thumb, you have to consider that the noise after modulus switching is larger than $N$. In particular, it will never have only 5 bits, as in your example, because $N$ is typically larger than $2^{13}$ in the FV scheme.

**In more detail.**

Let's say you have an RLWE ciphertext $c = (a, b) \in R_Q^2$, with $b = a\cdot s + e + (q / t) \cdot m$, as in the FV scheme.

Similarly to what is explained [in this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66186/what-is-modulo-switching-in-a-nutshell/87971#87971), but using polynomials instead of vectors, after we perform a modulus switching from $Q$ to some $q$, we get a new ciphertext with noise term given by

$$e' := e \cdot q / Q + \epsilon' + \epsilon \cdot s$$

where both $\epsilon'$ and $\epsilon$ are polynomials with coefficients in the interval $[-1/2,\, 1/2]$.

Usually, it is true that the new error $e'$ is close to the scaled error $e \cdot Q / q$ because the other terms are small compared to this one. However, when the scaled error becomes too small, that is no longer true, as $\epsilon \cdot s$ starts to dominate the norm of $e'$, and this is the "limit of modulus switching". In more detail, the norm of $\epsilon \cdot s$ can be as big as $N \cdot || \epsilon || \cdot || s ||$. So, even using binary or ternary keys (thus $|| s || = 1$), we have
$N \cdot || \epsilon || \cdot || s || = N \cdot || \epsilon || \approx N/2$.

Comment: Thanks yeah its very clear to me now, I missed the rounding errors. So with this information, it looks like we can have $q'$ of around $35$ bits (just to be on safe side) in my above example?

Comment: @muhammadharis yes, if $N$ is not too big, this should be good.