# Hardness of LWE

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, lwe, ring-lwe

I was reading ["TFHE Deep Dive" from Ilaria Chillotti](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npoHSR6-oRw&t=2674s), and I am a bit confused over the sample given in 31:08
[image]
In the above toy sample, isn't it possible to directly eliminate noise by shifting ciphertext by $\Delta$, then by Gaussian Elimination yielding plaintext?

In general, while intuitively original LWE hardness make sense (errors taken from $D_{L,r}$ with $r\geq \eta_\epsilon(L)$, so support of error cover then whole modulus), I don't really understand how are schemes keeping noise completely separate from plaintext (like above) secure, can't I just discard the noisy bits and do regular gaussian elimination ...?

This is probably a dumb question. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Try to think better about what you mean by "discard the noisy bits"...

Comment: The noise can also be negative, no? The top part of the message would then be altered and truncating the bits would give the wrong data.

Answer (score 4):

Discarding the noisy bits just means that you are "overwriting" that noise with new noise, essentially.

If $b = as + e$ and the norm of $e$ is bounded by $2^k$,
then zeroing the noisy bits means that you are computing
$u = b \bmod 2^k$ and
$b' = b - u$.
Notice that the $k$ lowest bits of $b'$ are zero.
But what you obtained is just
$b' = as + e - u$. Also notice that since $b$ is random, $u$ is also so (although it is known).

Therefore the noise is always there anyway.

Comment: What I mean is to perform rescale over the entire ciphertext $(a,b)$, rather than the $b$ term only. A rescale homomorphically performs division and round to nearest element, hence removing the lower bits containing noise, leaving a valid encryption of zero with no noise. Having said that though, I am not really sure how to *homomorphically* perform division, aside from knowing CKKS being able to achieve it.

Comment: Zeroing the lowest bits takes values from $\mathbb{Z}_q$ and outputs values of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ again. Rescaling is different because it also reduces the modulus. That is, if you divide a ciphertext whose noise is $e$ by some $D$ that divides $q$, then you output a ciphertext with noise close to $e/D$ but modulus $q/D$. So the relative noise is essentially the same, i.e., $(e/D) / (q/D) = e / q$, thus the "security of both ciphertexts" is basically the same (remember that the hardness of LWE depends on the ration "norm of noise" over "ciphertext modulus").

Comment: But if $|e|<\frac{D}{2}$, does that mean rescale lead to valid encryption with zero noise? since $(e/D)=0$

Comment: e/D is not zero. Round(e/D) would be zero in this case, but you don't round the error when you round the ciphertext. Moreover, there are actually other noise terms included by the rounding. I suggest that you check my answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66186) to see the exact equations.